# preg replace content between tags and also the tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have regex which works fine for me at https://regex101.com for searching xml tags and content between them, but when I use this regex in `preg_replace` or `preg_match`, it throws warning, that *Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash*. How should I edit this command to make it work please? I have to remove those tags and content between them.

Regex is:

```
\<mc\:AlternateContent\>[\s\S]*?\<\/mc:AlternateContent\>
```

And preg replace (regex is inside the constant):

```
preg_replace(self::REGEX_PATTERN_ALTERNATE_CONTENT, '', $paragraph->asXML());
```

XML:

```
  <mc:AlternateContent>
                    <mc:Choice Requires="wps">
                        <w:drawing>
                            <wp:anchor distT="0" distB="0" distL="114300" distR="114300" simplePos="0"
                                       relativeHeight="251666432" behindDoc="0" locked="1" layoutInCell="0"
                                       allowOverlap="1">
                                <wp:simplePos x="0" y="0"/>
                                <wp:positionH relativeFrom="page">
                                    <wp:posOffset>6387465</wp:posOffset>
                                </wp:positionH>
                                <wp:positionV relativeFrom="page">
                                    <wp:posOffset>2776855</wp:posOffset>
                                </wp:positionV>
                                <wp:extent cx="227965" cy="635"/>
                                <wp:effectExtent l="15240" t="14605" r="13970" b="13335"/>
                                <wp:wrapNone/>
                                <wp:docPr id="8" name="Přímá spojnice 8"/>
                                <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                                    <a:graphicFrameLocks
                                            xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"/>
                                </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                                <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
                                    <a:graphicData
                                            uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
                                        <wps:wsp>
                                            <wps:cNvCnPr>
                                                <a:cxnSpLocks noChangeShapeType="1"/>
                                            </wps:cNvCnPr>
                                            <wps:spPr bwMode="auto">
                                                <a:xfrm>
                                                    <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                                                    <a:ext cx="227965" cy="635"/>
                                                </a:xfrm>
                                                <a:prstGeom prst="line">
                                                    <a:avLst/>
                                                </a:prstGeom>
                                                <a:noFill/>
                                                <a:ln w="12700">
                                                    <a:solidFill>
                                                        <a:srgbClr val="000000"/>
                                                    </a:solidFill>
                                                    <a:round/>
                                                    <a:headEnd/>
                                                    <a:tailEnd/>
                                                </a:ln>
                                                <a:extLst>
                                                    <a:ext uri="{909E8E84-426E-40DD-AFC4-6F175D3DCCD1}">
                                                        <a14:hiddenFill
                                                                xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main">
                                                            <a:noFill/>
                                                        </a14:hiddenFill>
                                                    </a:ext>
                                                </a:extLst>
                                            </wps:spPr>
                                            <wps:bodyPr/>
                                        </wps:wsp>
                                    </a:graphicData>
                                </a:graphic>
                                <wp14:sizeRelH relativeFrom="page">
                                    <wp14:pctWidth>0</wp14:pctWidth>
                                </wp14:sizeRelH>
                                <wp14:sizeRelV relativeFrom="page">
                                    <wp14:pctHeight>0</wp14:pctHeight>
                                </wp14:sizeRelV>
                            </wp:anchor>
                        </w:drawing>
                    </mc:Choice>
                    <mc:Fallback>
                        <w:pict>
                            <v:line w14:anchorId="4CB34296" id="Přímá spojnice 8" o:spid="_x0000_s1026"
                                    style="position:absolute;z-index:251666432;visibility:visible;mso-wrap-style:square;mso-width-percent:0;mso-height-percent:0;mso-wrap-distance-left:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-top:0;mso-wrap-distance-right:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-bottom:0;mso-position-horizontal:absolute;mso-position-horizontal-relative:page;mso-position-vertical:absolute;mso-position-vertical-relative:page;mso-width-percent:0;mso-height-percent:0;mso-width-relative:page;mso-height-relative:page"
                                    from="502.95pt,218.65pt" to="520.9pt,218.7pt"
                                    o:gfxdata="UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQC2gziS/gAAAOEBAAATAAAAW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbJSRQU7DMBBF&#xA;90jcwfIWJU67QAgl6YK0S0CoHGBkTxKLZGx5TGhvj5O2G0SRWNoz/78nu9wcxkFMGNg6quQqL6RA&#xA;0s5Y6ir5vt9lD1JwBDIwOMJKHpHlpr69KfdHjyxSmriSfYz+USnWPY7AufNIadK6MEJMx9ApD/oD&#xA;OlTrorhX2lFEilmcO2RdNtjC5xDF9pCuTyYBB5bi6bQ4syoJ3g9WQ0ymaiLzg5KdCXlKLjvcW893&#xA;SUOqXwnz5DrgnHtJTxOsQfEKIT7DmDSUCaxw7Rqn8787ZsmRM9e2VmPeBN4uqYvTtW7jvijg9N/y&#xA;JsXecLq0q+WD6m8AAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQA4/SH/1gAAAJQBAAALAAAAX3JlbHMvLnJl&#xA;bHOkkMFqwzAMhu+DvYPRfXGawxijTi+j0GvpHsDYimMaW0Yy2fr2M4PBMnrbUb/Q94l/f/hMi1qR&#xA;JVI2sOt6UJgd+ZiDgffL8ekFlFSbvV0oo4EbChzGx4f9GRdb25HMsYhqlCwG5lrLq9biZkxWOiqY&#xA;22YiTra2kYMu1l1tQD30/bPm3wwYN0x18gb45AdQl1tp5j/sFB2T0FQ7R0nTNEV3j6o9feQzro1i&#xA;OWA14Fm+Q8a1a8+Bvu/d/dMb2JY5uiPbhG/ktn4cqGU/er3pcvwCAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAA&#xA;IQCg2SOsKQIAADcEAAAOAAAAZHJzL2Uyb0RvYy54bWysU82O0zAQviPxDlbubZJu+hc1XaGk5bJA&#xA;pV0ewLWdxuDYlu02rRAPwpEH4ClWvBdjN622cEGIHJyxPfPNNzOfF/fHVqADM5YrWUTpMIkQk0RR&#xA;LndF9PFpPZhFyDosKRZKsiI6MRvdL1+/WnQ6ZyPVKEGZQQAibd7pImqc03kcW9KwFtuh0kzCZa1M&#xA;ix1szS6mBneA3op4lCSTuFOGaqMIsxZOq/NltAz4dc2I+1DXljkkigi4ubCasG79Gi8XON8ZrBtO&#xA;ehr4H1i0mEtIeoWqsMNob/gfUC0nRllVuyFRbazqmhMWaoBq0uS3ah4brFmoBZpj9bVN9v/BkveH&#xA;jUGcFhEMSuIWRrT5+e35R/v8HVmtPkngh2a+TZ22OXiXcmN8oeQoH/WDIp8tkqpssNyxQPfppAEj&#xA;9RHxTYjfWA3Jtt07RcEH750KPTvWpvWQ0A10DKM5XUfDjg4ROByNpvPJOEIEriZ34wCP80ukNta9&#xA;ZapF3igiwaVvG87x4cE6zwTnFxd/LNWaCxFGLyTqgO5omiQhwirBqb/1ftbstqUw6IC9esLXJ75x&#xA;M2ovaUBrGKar3naYi7MN2YX0eFAM8Omtszy+zJP5araaZYNsNFkNsqSqBm/WZTaYrNPpuLqryrJK&#xA;v3pqaZY3nFImPbuLVNPs76TQP5qzyK5ivfYhvkUPDQOyl38gHabpB3iWwlbR08ZcpgzqDM79S/Ly&#xA;f7kH++V7X/4CAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQCc4vUx4QAAAA0BAAAPAAAAZHJzL2Rvd25yZXYu&#xA;eG1sTI/BTsMwEETvSPyDtUjcqN020BDiVAhUVVRc2iJx3SZLHIjXaey24e9xucBxZp9mZ/L5YFtx&#xA;pN43jjWMRwoEcemqhmsNb9vFTQrCB+QKW8ek4Zs8zIvLixyzyp14TcdNqEUMYZ+hBhNCl0npS0MW&#xA;/ch1xPH24XqLIcq+llWPpxhuWzlR6k5abDh+MNjRk6Hya3OwGvB5uQ7v6WQ1a17M6+d2sV+adK/1&#xA;9dXw+AAi0BD+YDjXj9WhiJ127sCVF23USt3eR1ZDMp1NQZwRlYzjnN2vlYAscvl/RfEDAAD//wMA&#xA;UEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhALaDOJL+AAAA4QEAABMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFtDb250ZW50X1R5&#xA;cGVzXS54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAOP0h/9YAAACUAQAACwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAvAQAAX3Jl&#xA;bHMvLnJlbHNQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAoNkjrCkCAAA3BAAADgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAuAgAAZHJz&#xA;L2Uyb0RvYy54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAnOL1MeEAAAANAQAADwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACDBAAA&#xA;ZHJzL2Rvd25yZXYueG1sUEsFBgAAAAAEAAQA8wAAAJEFAAAAAA==&#xA;"
                                    o:allowincell="f" strokeweight="1pt">
                                <w10:wrap anchorx="page" anchory="page"/>
                                <w10:anchorlock/>
                            </v:line>
                        </w:pict>
                    </mc:Fallback>
                </mc:AlternateContent>
```

Comment: can you share your XML string?

Comment: @SahilGulati sure, I will add it to question